# Is it possible to pull from multiple tables and then insert the result into another table in the same query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sequelize.js

I'm querying multiple tables with `UNION ALL` and then using the alias to insert the result into another table.  It's telling me that I have a syntax error right after the `INSERT INTO` line.  The query looks correct to me and the error is pretty vague.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
            SELECT
                uploads.campaign_name as 'Campaign Name'
            , date as Date
            , country as Country
            , region as Region
            , amount_spent as 'Amount Spent'
            , impressions as Impressions
            , clicks as Clicks
            , cpc as CPC
            , ctr as CTR
            , cpm as CPM
            , category as Category
            , subcategory as Subcategory
            , source as Source 

            FROM (SELECT
                facebook.ad_name as campaign_name
            , facebook.day as 'date'
            , CASE WHEN facebook.account_name = 'PMD Beauty' THEN 'US'
                WHEN facebook.account_name = 'PMD Beauty United Kingdom' THEN 'UK'
                WHEN facebook.account_name = 'PMD Beauty Australia' THEN 'AU'
                WHEN facebook.account_name = 'PMD Beauty Europe' THEN 'EU' END as country
            , facebook.region as region
            , facebook.amount_spent as amount_spent
            , facebook.impressions as impressions
            , facebook.clicks as clicks
            , facebook.cpc as cpc
            , facebook.ctr as ctr
            , facebook.cpm as cpm
            , 'Facebook' as source
                
            FROM
                facebook
                
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                tiktok.campaign_name as campaign_name
            , tiktok.date as 'date'
            , tiktok.location as country
            , null as region
            , tiktok.cost as amount_spent
            , tiktok.impression as impressions
            , tiktok.click as clicks
            , tiktok.cpc as cpc
            , tiktok.ctr as ctr
            , tiktok.cpm as cpm
            , 'Tiktok' as source
            
            FROM
                tiktok
                
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                pinterest.ad_name as campaign_name
            , pinterest.date as 'date'
            , trim(substring_index(pinterest.targeting_value, ':', 1)) as country
            , trim(substring_index(pinterest.targeting_value, ':', -1)) as region
            , pinterest.spend_in_account_currency as amount_spent
            , pinterest.impressions as impressions
            , pinterest.link_clicks as clicks
            , pinterest.cpc as cpc
            , pinterest.ctr as ctr
            , pinterest.cpm as cpm
            , 'Pinterest' as source
            
            FROM
                pinterest
                
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                steelhouse.campaign_group_name as campaign_name
            , steelhouse.date as 'date'
            , null as country
            , null as region
            , steelhouse.total_spend as amount_spent
            , steelhouse.impressions as impressions
            , null as clicks
            , null as cpc
            , null as ctr
            , null as cpm
            , 'SteelHouse' as source
            
            FROM
                steelhouse
                    
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                criteo.campaign as campaign_name
            , criteo.day as 'date'
            , null as country
            , null as region
            , criteo.cost as amount_spent
            , criteo.displays as impressions
            , criteo.clicks as clicks
            , criteo.cpc as cpc
            , criteo.ctr as ctr
            , criteo.cpm as cpm
            , 'Criteo' as source
            
            FROM
                criteo
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                hivewyre.creative_name as campaign_name
            , hivewyre.date as 'date'
            , 'US' as country
            , null as region
            , hivewyre.spend as amount_spent
            , hivewyre.imps as impressions
            , hivewyre.clicks as clicks
            , null as cpc
            , null as ctr
            , null as cpm
            , 'Hivewyre' as source
            
            FROM
                hivewyre
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT
                generic_social_media.campaign_name as campaign_name
            , generic_social_media.date as 'date'
            , generic_social_media.country as country
            , generic_social_media.region as region
            , generic_social_media.amount_spent as amount_spent
            , generic_social_media.impressions as impressions
            , generic_social_media.clicks as clicks
            , generic_social_media.cpc as cpc
            , generic_social_media.ctr as ctr
            , generic_social_media.cpm as cpm
            , 'Generic Template' as source
            
            FROM
                generic_social_media) uploads
            
            LEFT JOIN
                product_to_category
                ON uploads.campaign_name LIKE BINARY concat('%', product_to_category.product, '%')

            WHERE uploads.date >= :startDate

            INSERT INTO
                marketing (campaign_name, category, subcategory, 'date', country, region, amount_spent, impressions, clicks, cpc, ctr, cpm, source, plenadata__created_at, plenadata__updated_at)
                
            SELECT
                campaign_name
            , category
            , subcategory
            , 'date'
            , country
            , region
            , amount_spent
            , impressions
            , clicks
            , cpc
            , ctr
            , cpm
            , source
            , NOW()
            , NOW()

            FROM
                uploads
```

In the terminal:

```
`error`='\t\t\t\tmarketing (campaign_name, category, subcategory, \'date\', country\' at line 149',`stack`='SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Comment: The basic syntax is `INSERT INTO tablename (columns...) SELECT ...`. You can't put the `INSERT` clause after `SELECT`.

Comment: You can't use a subquery as a table name in `FROM uploads`. It seems like you're expecting the earlier `SELECT` query to act like a CTE.

Comment: @Barmar so the error is occurring because I'm using `INSERT INTO` after a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: They're not separate statements, there's no `;` between them. It's a single query, and you have the syntax backwards.

Comment: You wrote `SELECT ... INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` It should just be `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x, you can use a CTE: `WITH upload AS (SELECT ...) INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM uploads`